# Server 2008 R2 Black Screen (not BSOD) crash, no errors to report

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am having a very strange problem occur on a brand new Server 2008 R2 x64 server install with brand new hardware.  I even returned/exchanged Motherboard & CPU thinking it may have been defective.  Problem remains

- Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 with SP1,and all windows updates applied.
- Asus P8H67-PRO H67 chipset w/ Core i5
  2500K (using intel HD graphics w/
  win7 x64 drivers)
- 2x4GB Corsair memory
- Latest MB Bios (1002)
- Hyper-V NOT ENABLED
- Desktop Experience enabled
- OCZ Vertex2 2.5" SSD 160 GB (may be
  relevant?)

Behavior:

Server will remain powered on, but with no video, essentially locked up. No networking (ping unresponsive), keyboard lights do not respond to caps or NUM lock. It's as though the machine is OFF, though the fans are still spinning in the case.

This occurs at random times. Not related to load, heat, uptime, application usage. In fact it happens when server is idle.  It will be fine one minute, and I revisit the monitor an hour or two later, black screen, have to manually power off/on. Typically happens for sure overnight when I check on server in the morning, but does not happen after a specific amount of time.

Nothing in the C:\Windows\minidump folder, no kernel dump. I have been witness to the lockup just once while at the monitor. It just went black like it would if the power settings kicked in and killed video to the monitor... except moving mouse and hitting keyboard does not wake it up, and again it's not reachable on the network.

There are absolutely NO errors to reference, and no way to trigger or forcefully reproduce the issue. Don't know how to fix this.

I need ideas, something not obvious.

**Update**

Look at this: http://www.gskill.us/forum/showthread.php?t=8390

Seems to be an issue with Asus P8H67 This poor guy thinks it's his ram as he's posting on the gskill.us forums. I feel his pain.

I'm going to have to consider other MB manufacturer. MSI or Gigabyte will do (though I hear MSI has EFI bios also, gigabyte is some hybrid).

NOTE: I have a Shuttle SH67H3 which is the H67 chipset, and I have the same Corsair memory, and the same Core i5 2500k CPU... OCZ SSD and NO PROBLEMS. It's got to be something with Asus H67 boards.

Comment: Smells like hardware from here.  Reseat memory, swap anything you can, all the usual troubleshooting stuff...  Good luck!

Comment: I'd think the same, problem is I did swap MB and CPU yesterday.  Only thing that remains is memory which has been reseated as part of the MB swapout... (memtest86 4.2 for sandybridge runs for hours w/o a problem), the power supply (brand new antec BP-550), and the Antec Sonata Proto case, and the Vertex2 SSD.

Comment: Do you see any events in the event log?  Particualy PCI bus errors?

Comment: I'll check when I get home.  Server went dark on me about an hour ago after being up and running fine all day long :(   Such a pain!

Comment: On-board video and network?

Comment: Yes to both.  Video in particular is the graphics included with the new sandybridge LGA 1155 CPUs (one of the reason I sent CPU along with motherboard for exchange).    Not to distract, but I've got a little brand new shuttle SH67H3 with the exact same core i5 2500k CPU with the same corsair memory modules, and similar size OCZ Vertex2 SSD drive.... No problems there.

Comment: Memory errors usually would be more visible - with ECC through reported ECC errors, but even without ECC through bluescreens or protection failures in running applications. If the system just halts, i'd suspect either a thermal (something overheats) or a voltage problem (voltage at CPU or memory controller drops suddenly)

Comment: Thanks.  Thermal situation was much worse before the MB+CPU exchange yesterday as I purchased one of those Zalman radial heatsink/fan combos... cut temperature of CPU in half.  It's about 33C now which is quite cool for the CoreI3/I5/I7 CPUs.     I'll take this to mean voltage is a suspect.    I can try using my main tower's PSU for a few days as a troubleshooting step.  Thanks

Comment: I've got my workstation tower open, with all power cables going into the open case of the new troublesome server.  It's on, idling and I'm waiting.  I'm hoping it's online 24 hours from now (never been up for more than 12 hours since I began using it 5 days ago).

Comment: Interesting situation your having. Have you checked the power settings in BIOS and under windows? let us know what happens.

Comment: Maybe your electrical installation is bad. You could try to plug the server to a small uninterruptible power supply. These supplies protect in a certain way if a power sag is coming from your installation. You could also try to power your server from another electric circuit in another room. But this is just an idea and maybe a bit farfetched...

Comment: I moved the problematic server into another room last night, hooked it up to the power supply of my workstation (on 24/7 no probs).   STILL went black this at 2:27am.  So to recap, I've replaced MB, CPU, hooked up known good power supply.  Only things I have not replaced are the computer CASE, and the SSD drive.  I'm grasping at straws here... next step is disconnecting SSD drive and doing a linux LIVE CD and see how long that survives.  Then remove MB from the CASE and place it unprotected on the antistatic bag and retry linux LIVE cd.  My gosh, what could it be

Comment: Power settings in BIOS are default, I honestly have not looked much at it though behavior is same on two different ASUS boards, and so I imagine default settings would not contribute to system instability like this.   As for windows, it's server 2008 R2 so all sleep modes are set to NEVER by default, but I did verify that a few days ago.

Comment: "Only things I have not replaced are the computer CASE, and the SSD drive" So you have not changed the SSD? Maybe try to replace it with a SATA HDD?

Comment: Hi Robert,
I have almost the exact same hardware as you listed, same CPU, motherboard, RAM, operating system and the Hyper-V settings.
Apart from the SSD it seems to be identical (I'm using a SATA 600 drive) and I am having the same kind of problem.
It hangs for me too at random times, error log doesn't really give me anything useful.
It's also unresponsive and because the monitor turns off after a while it stays black.
After I turned off the setting that makes the monitor turn off after a set period of time I could see a whole bunch of colored lines in the screen after it crashed.
I have also

Comment: Hi OptiDash,  I didnt' even mention the colored garbled video lines as I only saw that PRE motherboard & CPU swap.  I chalked it up to a bad board or CPU, but I DID have that exact issue you describe with the video, saw it twice.  Haven't seen it since board & cpu swap but that could be coincidence.  There's an obvious very low level (bios/firmware) issue at play here, and I"m surprised it's not WAY more commonly reported.

Comment: I reproduced the problem using a Linux LIVE CD for Ubuntu, with all hard drives unplugged.  So SSD was out of the picture, and it wasn't even windows.  This means the category I posted this in originally is misleading as I don't believe it to be related to Windows Server 2008 R2 any longer.

Comment: Hear hear for Tier 1 vendor hardware built for servers...

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem on a domain controller that would forget who it is and start failing but demoting it fixed it.  With the LiveCD check, it seems hardware.  What about mounting a data folder for the LiveCD to save /var/log/ or configure it to output to a central server.

If the machine is configured to bug check output to a serial port, then VGA may get turned off and you do not see the BSOD?  Is it configured to save a dump?

Does it happen in safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

like I said before I had the same problem but since I've switched from Server 2008 R2 to Ubuntu Server I have not had any problems at all.
It's possible that it's still going to happen, but ofcourse I sure hope not.
I think what was causing problems (for me) is the Windows 7 x64 drivers, especially the USB 3.0 driver from the Asus website was causing some problems even during installation.
I have tried reinstalling Server 2008 R2 and getting all the drivers from the intel website, which are were labeled for Server 2008 R2.
It took a while to find them but I found all of them apart from the USB 3.0 one.
I left it on for two full days and it didn't crash. After that I still decided to go with Ubuntu Server for various reasons.
Since you were also using Windows 7 drivers this might be worth a try, that is, if you haven't already switched motherboards.
I'm not sure why it crashed for you with a Ubuntu live CD, maybe we're not having the same problem after all... or maybe I've just been lucky so far :)
Anyway, I'm blaming the Windows 7 drivers.